# Pointers, arrays, and structs (and allocating memory)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

okay, this is probably really simple, but i looked all over the site about pointers, arrays, and memory allocation, but some explanations are a bit too complex for me.  So... could someone explain to me why d[i] are pointing to different things in the below code?

```
typedef struct data_t {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
} data_t;

void f1(data_t **d);
int main()
{
data_t *d; 
    d = new data_t[500];
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        d[i].ival= i+1;
        d[i].sval="$";
    }

    f1(&d); 
}

void f1(data_t **d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        d[i]->ival=i+1;
        d[i]->sval="$";
    }
}
```

though what i need to do is fill in each of the 500 elements of the array such that the integer field ‘ival’ has the values 1-500 for array indexes 0-499, and the string field ‘sval’ contains the string “$1” – “$500” for array indexes 0-499. in the function call.

also:  is

```
d = new data_t[500]
```

all i need to allocate memory for a 500 element array of structures?

just trying to figure out why it works in the for loop in main, but not in the function call...  looking at the debugger the pointers are pointing at something way wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It works" in `main` because `d[i]` is the same as `*(d + i)`. In your function `f1`, `d` is a pointer to a pointer, so you need to say `(*d)[i].ival` etc. (What you wrote, `d[i]`, is advancing the pointer to the pointer by `i` steps and then tries to dereference *that*, which is the wrong way round.)

Then again, since you're in C++, you should probably just have passed the pointer as a reference:

```
 void f2(data_t * & d)  // <--- reference to the original pointer
 {
     // ...
     d[i].ival = i + 1;
 }
```

Or actually, since you're never changing the original `d` itself, only what it *points* to , you can even pass it by *value*:

```
void f3(data_t * d)     // <--- pointer passed by value
{
     // as before, d[i].ival etc.
}
```

Or rather, you should probably use a `std::vector<data_t>` and not use *any* pointers at all. (Also, you shouldn't typedef your class definition of `data_t`.)

Comment: awesome this was exactly the problem...  
now  how would i go about changing the int i to sval?  this is way wrong but an example

     sval = ('$' + char(i+1) + '\0');

Comment: @Sun: Change `char*` to `std::string`.

Comment: yeah i know that would work, but this is actually for a test for an interview... requirements and whatnot

i'm 100% sure they want me to use malloc()  somewhere since it's mentioned...

Comment: @Sun: If it's a C++ interview and they ask you about `char*` and `malloc`, don't take the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f1` waits for an argument of type ** (i.e array of arrays, or just a matrix).
So when you write d[i] it is not a single element, but it is an array(row of a matrix). That's why neither `d[i].ival` nor `d[i] -> ival` will work.
I think the best solution for you is to use `std::vector` from STL.